# read color property by DOM manipualation , i want to read the value of body's backgroundColor . but the result be an empty string

Tags: javascript, css, dom

i already set the background color in css file ,
and iwant to read it and change by javascript
var backgroundColor = document.querySelector("body").style.backgroundColor;

if change the color it works , but I want to store the value and use it in if contiditon

Answer (score 1):

Try using [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

```
const backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("body")).backgroundColor
```

Answer (score 1):

.style only works for defined inline styles. You need to use .getComputedStyle(ele):

```
 var backgroundColor = getComputedStyle(document.querySelector("body")).backgroundColor;
```

Also consider [document.stylesheets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentOrShadowRoot/styleSheets).

Answer (score 0):

You can change background color by following ways-

1. if you want to change background color by body tag

   ```
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
   ```
2. if want to change background color of an element Id

   ```
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "lightblue";
    document.getElementById("myDiv").style.backgroundColor = "#ffffff";
   ```
3. if you are using jquery

   ```
   $("#myDiv").css( "background-color", "green");
   ```

Comment: OP is asking to **read** the value, not set it

Comment: Oops my mistake !!!

Comment: no problem , thank you for you effort